# SBT: which files to put under version control?

Tags: scala, version-control, sbt

I created a Scala project with SBT, referencing ScalaTest. Now it has this tree:

```
├───lib
├───lib_managed
│   └───scala_2.9.0
│       └───compile
├───project
│   ├───boot
│   │   ├───other
│   │   │   └───net.java.dev.jna
│   │   │       └───jna
│   │   │           └───3.2.3
│   │   ├───scala-2.7.7
│   │   │   ├───lib
│   │   │   └───org.scala-tools.sbt
│   │   │       └───sbt
│   │   │           └───0.7.7
│   │   │               ├───compiler-interface-bin_2.7.7.final
│   │   │               ├───compiler-interface-bin_2.8.0.final
│   │   │               ├───compiler-interface-bin_2.8.1.final
│   │   │               ├───compiler-interface-bin_2.9.0.final
│   │   │               ├───compiler-interface-src
│   │   │               └───xsbti
│   │   └───scala-2.9.0
│   │       └───lib
│   └───build
│       └───target
│           └───scala_2.7.7
│               ├───analysis
│               └───classes
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───resources
│   │   └───scala
│   └───test
│       ├───resources
│       └───scala
└───target
```

In addition to src tree, which files/directories should I put under version control (now using SVN)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For sbt 0.7, ignore the following:

```
lib_managed
target
project/boot
project/build/target
project/plugins/lib_managed
project/plugins/src_managed
project/plugins/target
project/plugins/project/build.properties
```

There's sbt 0.10.x now btw.

Answer (score 7):

For xsbt 0.10+, [here is my `.gitignore`](https://github.com/VonC/xsbt-template/blob/master/.gitignore), in my [xsbt template project](https://github.com/VonC/xsbt-template):

```
target/
project/boot/
*.jar
```

It is similar to the [official `.gitignore` in the xsbt project](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/0.13/.gitignore), but [Eugene's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738183/sbt-which-files-to-put-under-version-control/6738265#6738265) might be more complete.